# How to call local json file in react bootstrap table

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to call my local json file for the below code but it's not getting. please help.
How to call local json file in the place of below statement
" const { data } = await axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')" .

Could please help me with this.
And also please check the below code for your reference. I am using the react-bootstrap table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import the json file first

```
import jsondata from ‘./path/data.json’;
```

then parse and load it.

```
const data  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
```

Comment: I used like this belowbut its not working.                                                                            
   import invoicedate from '../pdf/inoivelist.json'                                                               useEffect(
    () => {
      const fetchInvoicelists = async () => {
        // const { data } = await axios(invoicedate)
        const data = JSON.parse(invoicedate)
        setPosts({ blogs: data })
        console.log(data)
      }
      fetchInvoicelists()
    }, [setPosts])

Comment: please help with this

Comment: getting this error VM7909:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Stringify the Json then parse it, edited the answer please check